# Can only print PDFs

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

I have Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, iMac 27 inch late 2013.  I can print any PDF but nothing else. In the print dialog box where I can normally see what I am about to print, it is blank. If I do print I get a blank sheet. If I save to PDF, you get a blank PDF except for a tiny box in the middle.

I have removed and reinstalled the print drivers. I have tried the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keypresses at startup.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the print dialog? Also, does it happen in all applications or only in one?

Comment: I would add a screenshot but that suggestion to reset CUPS worked.   THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

Try resettings CUPS (Common Unix Printing System). To do this right click on the printer in System Preferences and select Reset Printing System. You will need to re-install the printer afterwards but this can fix weird printing issues like the one you describe.

Comment: YES, that worked. Thank you so much.  I'm really glad to know about resetting CUPS.